# Turning on the Windows 10 feature "Windows Sandbox" fails and throws an error (0x800F0922)

Tags: windows-10, installation, sandbox

When trying to turn on the `Windows Sandbox` feature, the installation fails and throws `0x800F0922` with no concrete error message, it just says:

> The changes couldn't be completed. Please, reboot your computer and
>   try again.

[image]

Of course, I've tried it, but it didn't help.

There's a hyperlink pointing to the ["appropriate" page on Microsoft.com Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2734782/net-framework-3-5-installation-error-0x800f0906-0x800f081f-0x800f0907), where the error should be described. The steps that are provided, cannot be done because of a very simple reason: they say:

> 1. Open the .NET Framework installation files folder.
> 2. Open **Sources** folder
> 3. Right-click the **SXS** folder, and then click Properties.
> 4. etc.

There's no `Sources` folder, nor an `SXS` folder inside the .NET Framework installation files folder (`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework`or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64`) or the sub-folders (the different .NET versions). I even created the two missing folders manually to try these steps.

Do you know why I cannot install the `Windows Sandbox` feature and why I get this error code? I thought it is because I use Docker (on my PC) and they are somehow conflicting with each other, such as Docker and VMWare (when you enable virtualization from BIOS). But I use Docker on my laptop as well. And I could install `Windows Sandbox` on my laptop. Both my PC and Laptop have Windows 1909 installed.

---

Additional information:

1. Hyper-V is enabled on my PC
2. I turned off "Controlled folder access"
   from within Defender and tried (it didn't work).

Comment: Controlled Folder Access has nothing to do with adding/removing features - it firewalls your data folders, and any other directories added to it, from non-trusted executables - it's there as a safeguard against ransomware.  An internet connection is required to add features via the Turn Features On/Off menu, and if you have internet access _and_ .NET Framework is enabled in Turn Features On/Off, please issue, in the order listed: `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup` > `dism /online cleanup-image /restorehealth` > reboot > `sfc /scannow` > reboot > try to add it again

Comment: Check the prerequisites and the procedure to follow in this [Microsoft article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Kernel-Internals/Windows-Sandbox/ba-p/301849).

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly caused by the damage of the .net framework features. You can uncheck .net framework 3.5, .net framework 4.8, hyper-v and windows sandbox features in windows features. Then reboot your computer and check all the 4 features on again. Windows will automatically download needed files and fix there 4 features. Then reboot as required and windows sandbox will be enabled. Hope this works for you.